# Infinite list of Fibonacci numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, where-clause, fibonacci

Sorry for a question like this. I'm a very beginner programmer, and I'm just started to learn about Haskell. I recently ran into an exercise to implement a function in Haskell that returns an infinite list of Fibonacci numbers.  The following code was the answer to the exercise:

```
fibs :: [Int]
fibs = fibs2 0
 where
    fibs2 :: Int -> [Int]
    fibs2 x = (fib2) x : (fibs2 (x+1))
```

Can someone explain to me why we should declare another function (`fibs2`) here and what "where" does in this case?

Comment: How is `fib2` defined ??

Comment: `where` introduces a local definition and is covered early on in most introductions to Haskell.

Comment: fib2 is'nt defined!!

Comment: how could it make an infinite List?

Comment: `fib2` would appear to be a function such that `fib2 i` returns the `i`th Fibonacci number. `fibs2` is a function that just builds a list by computing one Fibonacci number at a time, then recursively generating the *rest* of them.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone explain to me why we should declare another function (`fibs2`) here?

You certainly aren't obligated to declare another function. However, this particular pattern is quite common. Think of it a bit like loop initialization in other languages. If you want to iterate some process, the easiest way to do that is to write a function that takes some information describing where you are in the iteration, does one step of the "loop", then calls itself with a suitably modified description. For example, if you wanted to sum up all the numbers from 0 to n, you might write:

```
sumTo :: Int -> Int
sumTo 0 = 0
sumTo n = n + foo (n-1)
```

BUT frequently the function or value you want is actually the one that starts at a specific value. It's annoying to force all callers of your loop to specify that starting value; and the fact that you've implemented your loop as a recursive function with an argument is an implementation detail they shouldn't have to worry about anyway. So what to do? Well, you define something that calls the loop with the right starting value.

```
gauss :: Int
gauss = sumTo 100
```

This way, users can just use `gauss` and not have to know that `100` is the right starting value for your internal function.

> Can someone explain to me what "where" does in this case?

Well, there's one more thing that's a bit unfortunate about our previous `sumTo`/`gauss` values: we aren't really interested in `sumTo` itself, only in `gauss`, and the fact that it's visible outside of `gauss` is a violation of an abstraction barrier! If it's easy to call, it may be that somebody else tries to use it; then, if we need to change it to improve what `gauss` does, we are improving `gauss` but potentially breaking what that other user is using `sumTo` for. So we'd like to hide its existence.

That is the purpose of `where` here: it allows you to define a new thing that's accessible only locally. So:

```
gauss :: Int
gauss = sumTo 100 where
    sumTo 0 = 0
    sumTo n = n + sumTo (n-1)
```

In this variant, `gauss` can be called, but outside of the implementation of `gauss`, it isn't possible to call `sumTo`, maintaining a nice abstraction boundary.